# How to include boomerangjs script file in Angular 7?

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement boomerangjs in my Angular code. But it's not working for me. I need your help to resolve it. Below is the way I've used it. So first I've installed boomerangjs using npm and it's now available in my node_modules.
My first page is dashboard.component.ts, so I've added below code in this component.

```js
    import {BOOMR} from 'node_modules/boomerangjs';

    export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
      ngOnInit() {         
         BOOMR.init({
          beacon_url: "/beacon"
        });   
        }
    }
```

However I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined` error. Please help how can I use "boomerangjs " in my angular code.

Edit 1 - I am able to see 3 dots ... on top of page where import is listed. When I hover on dots getting below message:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'node_modules/boomerangjs'. 'd:/code/node_modules/boomerangjs/boomerang.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/boomerangjs` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'boomerangjs';`
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `import { BOOMR } from 'boomerangjs'`

Comment: Yes, I've but I was getting same error "Cannot read property 'init' of undefined".

Comment: What about `import * as BOOMR from 'boomerangjs'`

Comment: I just tried and getting "TypeError: boomerangjs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.init is not a function" error.

on top of page where I am importing this modules getting 3 dots, when I hover it I am seeing below message
Could not find a declaration file for module 'node_modules/boomerangjs'. 'd:/code/node_modules/boomerangjs/boomerang.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/boomerangjs` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'boomerangjs';`